# Question on sigsetjmp and siglongjmp

Tags: c, context-switch

I am trying to understand the `sigsetjmp()` and `siglongjmp()` functions. The man pages state that `sigsetjmp()` saves the context and `siglongjmp()` restores the context. My question is, will they take care of stack pointer and program counter values as well?

Any links to extra resources are welcome.

Comment: Isn't this like asking if a function call will return when its done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it takes care of all the context. What that is exactly is implementation dependent.

Be sure to read both the [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sigsetjmp.html) and your implementation's man pages, and be careful with these functions, they are tricky.

Comment: Can u please tell me what is implementation dependent? In all platforms, the SP and PC will be stored ,right? Also, can u give me an example of the differences between platforms?

Comment: Not all CPUs necessarily have a stack pointer or program counter (although I don't know concrete examples). The C++ (and C) standards don't mention these things because they are "implementation details". AFAIK, neither of those standards require a stack at all.

Answer (score 2):

The stack pointer and program counter are both parts of the context (which you can think of as being, essentially, the state of the CPU registers).